# SAS RGF Custom UI components

Tags: sas

I am trying to understand were are the custom components, which are referenced in UI definition are located?

E.g. I am trying to understand how component-name="WorkflowUI" works, but no clue were the file is located.

Can anyone help me to clarify how to find it? Maybe i can create some kind of rest request to acquire it? Couldn't find anything in documentations. It would be nice if you can at least give me a document where I can find the answer.